# Saving data inputs from all tabs - Android

Tags: android-tabhost

I have an android layout with 4 tabs. I have a Save button at the end of the layout to save all the inputs from those 4 tabs. How can I go through the tabs to gather the inputs and save the data? Is there is a specific method I could use from the tabhost to access the data in all the tabs at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the content views of each of the tabs and then iterate through those content views for children that can have values set and get their values.

Try looking at some of the functions for android.view.ViewGroup and android.view.View.